# Apply a computer object GPO to few users

Tags: group-policy

I want to restrict few domain users from installing new softwares. I have tried using the Poweruser and it is limiting the user. hence, I have added them as Administrators and tried applying the computer object policy to few users, however the policy is not taking effect. I have also enabled loopback.

Wanted to check, if I can apply a computer GPO to few users or please suggest me an alternate to overcome my issue.

Comment: Loopback processing mode is what you're looking for. It's purpose is to apply Computer-level settings irrespective of the logged-on user (and user settings, optionall). W/o specific details about your Active Directory (your OU structure, where you have the GPOs linked, where the Computer and User objects are, whether you've done any Security Group or WMI Filtering on the GPOs) there's nothing specific that I or anybody else can tell you. Provide more details and somebody can help you out. Look around for Loopback processing-related questions here and you might find some good assistance, too.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're adding people as administrators to *prevent* them from doing things.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your quick reply. I cannot find a better way to achieve this. I wanted to have the domain user run all the programs and also delete their respective files. I just want them not to install softwares, any ideas?